# Templates in function parameters

Tags: java, templates, types, vector

How can I define the type of a Vector by retrieving T from function's parameters?
Example:

```
public void addPlot(String plotName, int minX, int maxX,
        int minY, int maxY, PlotStyle plotStyle, Class<? extends Number> type)
{
    Vector<type.class> dataset = new Vector<type.class>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in Java, it's "generics", not "templates" (a C++ term).

Next, make your method generic with a named generic type parameter and use it.

```
// generic declaration after public, before void
public <T extends Number> void addPlot(String plotName, int minX, int maxX,
        int minY, int maxY, PlotStyle plotStyle, Class<T> type)
{
    Vector<T> dataset = new Vector<T>();
}
```

The `<T extends Number>` is your generic type parameter declaration (with an upper bound), and the other places where `<T>` shows up are where you use it.